# Extract the exact value from a list

Tags: python, json, list, split, extract

how can i extract the longitude and latitude from this -

> Feature(place='12km SSE of Volcano, Hawaii', long=-155.2005, lat=19.3258333, depth=6.97, mag=5.54)

Part of code is below

```
lrgst = features[0]
print ('\n',lrgst)
plt.bar(y_pos, magn)
plt.xticks(y_pos, loc)
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.show()


features = list(get_info()) #Storing our json information into a list 'Features'
```

Comment: Is the input (eg 'Feature..') meant to be a string that requires parsing or the instantiation of a class constructor?

Comment: Features is a data in a format of a list of all significant earthquakes(4.0+) all around the world, and that line that I showed as an example is not constant and will change every week, when the new data will be loaded to json of most significant earthquakes.And by using this. lrgst = features[0] I'm extracting the first line from a list, since I already sorted by magnitude and the earthquake with largest magnitude will always be the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "features" is a list of entries like the example given, this solution will work:

```
features = ["Feature(place='12km SSE of Volcano, Hawaii', long=-155.2005, lat=19.3258333, depth=6.97, mag=5.54)"]

def find(string, char_before, char_after):
    start = string.find(char_before) + len(char_before)
    end = string[start:].find(char_after) + start
    return string[start:end]

long = find(features[0], 'long=', ', ')
lat = find(features[0], 'lat=', ', ')

print(lat + ', ' + long)

    19.3258333, -155.2005
```

Comment: I will try it and respond here

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to extract using regex... but something is not working..

if this worked, then Alex's issue with will be resolved...

why it is not matching anything ?

```
place="12km SSE of Volcano, Hawaii', long=-155.2005, lat=19.3258333, depth=6.97, mag=5.54"

a1=re.match("r(long=)([\-\d\.]*)",place)
if a1:
     print (a1.groups(1))
```